# How do I move grub so that it's not on the MBR (so I can choose win7 / linux / osX from the refit menu)

Tags: windows-7, macos, ubuntu, multi-boot, grub

I've got a triple boot system with OSX, Ubuntu and Windows 7. Currently when I boot I get the [refit](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) menu first which sees all the partitions nicely, and if I choose os X it works just dandy, but if I choose either linux *or* win7 it goes to the grub menu and I then have to choose again. Sure it works, but it's tedious.

Now [I hear](http://refit.sourceforge.net/help/windows_boots_linux.html) that if I don't want to go to the grub menu when I choose windows, I have to install grub to the boot sector of the linux partition instead of the MBR. I've found a few instructions for how to do this when setting up a system, but not when it's already installed.

Can I move grub without having to reinstall windows and Ubuntu? TIA.

Comment: Are you on a MacBook?

Comment: both MBP and a desktop macpro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [install GRUB](http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/gnu/grub/html_chapter/grub_3.html) (the stage1 loader) in as many boot records you like (MBR and/or PBR). But to remove it from the MBR you have to overwrite it with something else. So you need to:

1. Install GRUB somewhere else (where rEFIt can find it).
2. Point rEFIt to the new GRUB location for loading Linux.
3. Install some bootloader in MBR for loading Windows only.